# Add color scale to GeoTiff from command line

Tags: command-line, colors, raster, qgis, geotiff

I have several hundred raster GeoTIFFs and a single color scale, and I need to assign the color scale to each raster. Adding the scale to each raster one-by-one in QGIS isn't feasible because this process needs to be done multiple times.

Is there a way to do this from the command-line, so I can script the process? I've been told to look at writing custom VRTs (just XML), but the documentation for doing so is sparse and seems geared towards GIS experts. I've been unable to find a GDAL utility to use for this task.

Comment: Could you give some details of the colour scale you'd like to apply?